# Angular - Load component dynamically on browser reload

Tags: angular, routes, components, page-refresh, angular11

This is more of a logical question. I've nested components & their routes in my application.
`Home component` houses few of the components which are loaded using `*ngIf` on fulfillment of certain conditions. On click of a button, certain components in the Home Component will get hidden while some appear in place of the hidden components and vice versa.

> Example: On click of Button1; Components A,B,C & D will be displayed. On
> Click of Button2; Components A,C,D & F will be displayed and so on..

I'm using Behaviour Subject to communicate via services.
Now, if I click on Button2, the rendered components are A,C,D & F. Let's say, I then move forward to click some element inside `component D`, which has further child routes.

> **Note:** `Component D` occupies a quarter of the view while rest of the `A,C & F components` are still visible besides it.

Now, If I hit the browser refresh button, it reloads the page, but due to the `If-Else` logic written inside .ts file of `home Component` (as shown below), it loads the rest of the components ie. `Components A,B,D & E`

```
if(clickedOnButton1){
Load Component A,
Load Component B,
Load Component C,
Load Component D,
}
else if(clickedOnButton2){
Load Component A,
Load Component C,
Load Component D,
Load Component F,
}
else{
Load Component A,
Load Component B,
Load Component D,
Load Component E,
}
```

Everything works fine at click of the desired button except the browser-refresh. How can I replicate the click of Button2 with browser-refresh? So that even If I click refresh, it would still load `A,C,D & F Components`. I tried using Behaviour Subject, ngOninit() but no luck.

Comment: you have to use some persistent storage, for example the most simple one is `sessionStorage`. storing this state in session storage would guarantee it will persist between refreshes

Comment: if i get your question right: you can't (inside of the typescript logic itself). Nothing persists on a reload, so not only do you run through the init() again (with the initial values) but all changes are lost. (feel free to prove me wrong, btw. it would be nice if something like this exists). So what I could think of is using the browsers local storage function. `localStorage.setItem('key', value)` and inside the onInit() use `localStorage.getItem('key')`